# Python request not returning full page contents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Currently I am working on a Python program to pull EDGAR data from sec.gov using a Python script. My the page I am trying to pull data from is [this](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1596783/000159678320000155/0001596783-20-000155.txt).

It appears to me that the data on this page is static, which is the reason I am trying to use Beautiful Soup and the Python Requests module to pull the data. Here is my script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()
dataLink = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1596783/000159678320000155/0001596783-20-000155.txt"
resp = requests.get(url=dataLink, verify=False, headers={"User-Agent":fake.chrome()})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'xml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

When I run this code, the data in the return is not even close the same number of entries to the data listed on the web page I am pulling the data from. Does anyone know why the return of my HTTP request would have a lot less data than is shown when I inspect the web page?

Comment: For ```resp```, do you mean ```response```?

Comment: It seems that if you run this request too often, SEC will limit the amount of requests. Could this be what you encountered?

Comment: If it is limiting you, then I suggest you write `resp.content` to a local HTML file and work from that

Comment: I'm for sure within the 10 request/second guideline so I don't think I am being limited